# Grabbing data from a query with specific criteria, then the data around it

Tags: mysql

The title may be slightly vague... however, this is the basis of what I want to do:
I have people in a database ranked on a statistic, for example, 'Kills'. I want to order the kills by highest to lowest, which I can already do, but this is where I run into an issue.

I would like to then have said query find a specific bit of data, a row with a specific 'Name' as defined in the query, then get 5 rows that would be above it, and 5 rows that would be below it. It would also be helpful if it does this in a timely fashion. If you need more detail, just ask!

For anyone wondering what research I've done, I've found queries that will do this, however those queries use full table scans, which would not be optimal in this case as there is 123k+ rows of data. Also, this is in mysql.

My current query that does a full table scan and doesn't work extremely well, nor effeciently, in general:

```
SELECT    allusers.rank, allusers.Name, allusers.Kills
FROM (
 SELECT   AgStats.Name,
        @t:=IF(score<=>@s,@t,@r) AS rank,
        @s:=AgStats.Kills AS Kills,
        @r:=@r+1
 FROM     AgStats, (SELECT @r:=0, @s:=NULL, @t:=NULL) init
 ORDER BY AgStats.Kills DESC
) allusers, (
 SELECT COUNT(*) AS rank
FROM   AgStats
WHERE  Kills > (SELECT Kills FROM AgStats WHERE Name = 'VoidWhisperer')
) user
WHERE    ABS(allusers.rank-user.rank) <= 5
ORDER BY allusers.rank
```

To give an example of what I'm trying to do: You have 10 rows of data, with the row kills on the end. I want to select a specific row out of those 10 based on name, then get a number of rows above it, in this case, 5 rows above/below, done via the query?

Comment: A full table scan can be pretty fast if the table is narrow enough.  And 123k rows is not that much.

Comment: @dezso - i can post the query I was using in the question if need be. I tried it with it, and it eventually gave up after a very long time and loaded alot more rows than it should've.

Comment: It can possibly help.  And do I understand you correctly: you want a window on your ordered data with a given user in the middle?

Comment: Yes. That is what I wanted, and I'll post the query I currently have, which does a full table scan and takes for ever in addition to not providing a window in the question.

Comment: The query I added doesn't work because it lists large numbers of users when it should only list 5. :/

Comment: Is `AgStats.Name` unique?

Comment: Yes, name is unique. No two people in it have the same name.

Comment: OK, I'll post an answer. But 2 or more users can have the same `Kills` and this complicates matters.

Answer (score 2):

First a query without `rank`. You may get more than 11 rows in the result, if there people with same number of `Kills` as your player:

```
  ( SELECT a.*
    FROM AgStats AS a 
      JOIN 
      ( SELECT Kills  FROM AgStats 
        WHERE Name = 'VoidWhisperer'
          LIMIT 1 
      ) AS k
      ON a.Kills > k.Kills
    ORDER BY a.Kills ASC
      LIMIT 5
  )
  UNION ALL
  ( SELECT a.*
    FROM AgStats AS a 
      JOIN 
      ( SELECT Kills  FROM AgStats 
        WHERE Name = 'VoidWhisperer'
          LIMIT 1 
      ) AS k
      ON a.Kills = k.Kills
  )
  UNION ALL
  ( SELECT a.*
    FROM AgStats AS a 
      JOIN 
      ( SELECT Kills  FROM AgStats 
        WHERE Name = 'VoidWhisperer'
          LIMIT 1 
      ) AS k
      ON a.Kills < k.Kills
    ORDER BY a.Kills DESC
      LIMIT 5
  ) 
ORDER BY Kills DESC ;
```

---

This will show no more than 11 rows, even if there hundreds of players with same number of `Kills`, by applying an order on the two columns: `Kills, Name`:

```
  ( SELECT a.*
    FROM AgStats AS a 
      JOIN 
      ( SELECT Kills, Name  FROM AgStats 
        WHERE Name = 'VoidWhisperer'
          LIMIT 1 
      ) AS k
      ON a.Kills = k.Kills AND a.Name > k.Name
      OR a.Kills > k.Kills
    ORDER BY a.Kills ASC, a.Name ASC
      LIMIT 5
  )
  UNION ALL
  ( SELECT a.*
    FROM AgStats AS a 
    WHERE Name = 'VoidWhisperer'
  )
  UNION ALL
  ( SELECT a.*
    FROM AgStats AS a 
      JOIN 
      ( SELECT Kills, Name  FROM AgStats 
        WHERE Name = 'VoidWhisperer'
          LIMIT 1 
      ) AS k
      ON a.Kills = k.Kills AND a.Name < k.Name
      OR a.Kills < k.Kills
    ORDER BY a.Kills DESC, a.Name DESC
      LIMIT 5
  ) 
ORDER BY Kills DESC, Name DESC ;
```

It will be good if you have a an index on `(Kills, Name)` and a (unique) index on `(Name)`.

Tested at **[SQL-Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/dfde2/2)**

Comment: Alot of users have 0-10 kills.. is it possible at all to prevent a massive # of duplicates showing up, because if the user has the same # of kills as about 100 of the other 123k people, it could lead to an issue.

Comment: Should it prevent the duplicates now? :)

Comment: Well, is there a way to prevent it from giving more than is applicable if people have the same # of kills? like if 1000 people have 0 kills, i need it to not end up spitting out 1000 entries.

Comment: See the second query.

Comment: Issue with using the name to compare it: If they have similar names, it will select ones with names like the first one: eg if the name contains super.. SuperBob,SuperMario, ETC. will selectpeople with name's beginning with super. So, is it possible to make a temporary variable to sort them by that is literal rank, or something else we could use to limit it to only 11, other than name, because name doesn't work if people have similar names, which in a table of 123k rows, is bound to happen. Alot.

Comment: You said that Name is unique. Ah, I see what you mean.

Comment: If you have a userID to sort instead of Name, it would work fine.

Comment: Wouldn't that still run into the issue of it would sort it based on user id and not only kills? Thus messing up the purely kill ranking?

Comment: I mean replacing `(Kills, Name)` with `(Kills, UserID)` in the `ORDER BY` and the two `ON` clauses.

Comment: or with `(Kills, LastUpdatedDate)`, whatever other column you may have in the stats table.

Comment: Ok... although If that works the same way the name did... that would still run into the same issue the name's did.

Comment: No, it won't. The ordering is on `Kills` first and then on `UserID` (or whatever) and.